# AppHarbor MVC - Unable to use HttpNoContent Status Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, appharbor

I need to be able to respond to requests with a http status code of 204 but appharbor is only returning a 500 error.  My controller code is executing correctly but when the code below is called, I only see a 500 error in fiddler.

```
protected ViewResult HttpNoContent()
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent;

    return View("NoContent");
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning a view with 204 (NoContent) status code? Does the `NoContent` view exist? You would usually return an `EmptyResult` for that purpose.

Comment: It's an endpoint for fitbit and they require us to return a 204 when the request is complete.

Comment: I understand that, but 204 status code means that you need to return an empty content i.e. no content. In your example you are returning a view. That's contradictory.

Comment: Ok, I see. What do I need to return then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from the [specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) (I have put the important part in bold):

> The 204 response **MUST NOT include a message-body**, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

You are not respecting this rule. 204 status code means no content and yet you are returning a view. Try returning an [EmptyResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.emptyresult.aspx):

```
protected ViewResult HttpNoContent()
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent;

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```